# Generate equals and hashCode in Record using tables primary key

Tags: java, jooq

Is there a way to tell jOOQ to generate equals() and hashCode() using the primary key of its table?

The use case is:

I'm using Records in Vaadin Grids. I can refresh single items in the grid but Vaadin uses equals to find the corresponding item in the grid.

Now in the UI the user can select a record and edit it. And after edit I want to refresh the record in the grid. As far as I cans see jOOQ is using all fields for equals() and because the row was changed equals() is no longer true.

Comment: Hey guys. Why do you downvote and add close requests? If you knew jOOQ you would know that this is a question that cannot be answered by reading the documentation.

Comment: Stack Overflow . What's the use case you're after?

Comment: @LukasEder I added the use case to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ being a SQL based API assumes that a record is a tuple with no identity. Thus comparing a record with another record defaults to comparing each attribute of r1 with each corresponding attribute of r2.

This works the same way as a `union` between two sets works, or the `distinct` operation in SQL, both of which don't care about IDs but only about the record's values.

It should be simple to override the built-in `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementation for POJOs and records. jOOQ's internals should not depend on this implementation for most features (but there's a slight risk this is incorrect, I don't remember).

I have created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8705. In the meantime, you will need to roll your own using a custom code section: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code/

Comment: Ok you got me :-) I now will definitely dig into code generation.